# waiting for JS async func to complete before running some sync code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have an async function `getDataItem` that returns a promise  and passes data to another function `preparePhysicianSchemaData` which builds a global object `physicianDetailsObj` out of the passed data as well as data fetched after calling yet another async function inside it for each row of data it was initially passed.

`getDataItem(listID, itemID).then(preparePhysicianSchemaData)`

Only after the global object variable `physicianDetailsObj` is fully populated, then I need to call another function called `buildSEOSchemaBlock()`, whose job is to parse `physicianDetailsObj` object and build the final object needed.

I would rather not use setTimeOut to try to time this:

```
      setTimeout(function(){ return getListItem(listID, itemID).then(preparePhysicianSchemaData) }, 10);
      setTimeout(function(){ return buildPhysicianSchemaBlock() }, 3000);
```

How can I chain the last function like this: `getDataItem(listID, itemID).then(preparePhysicianSchemaData).then(buildPhysicianSchemaBlock)` ensuring that the last function runs only after the global object variable `physicianDetailsObj` is fully populated?

```
    var physicianDetailsObj = {};
    function getListItem() {}  //returns promise
    function preparePhysicianSchemaData(item) {
        var tempPhysicianDetailsObj = {};   
        var currentPhysicianItemId = item.get_id();
    
        tempPhysicianDetailsObj = {
            "name" : item.get_item("Title"),
            "url" : item.get_item("SEOCanonicalHref").match('href="([^"]+)')[1]
        };
     
         var currentItemPhysicianTag= item.get_item("PhysicianItemTag").get_label();  
    
         getPhysicianLocationDetailsFromServiceLocations(currentItemPhysicianTag).then(function(slitems) {
            console.log(slitems);
            var slitemEnum = slitems.getEnumerator();
    
            //first empty the object
            Object.keys(physicianDetailsObj).forEach(k => delete physicianDetailsObj[k]);
    
            while (slitemEnum.moveNext()) {
                var slitem = slitemEnum.get_current();
                physicianDetailsObj[currentPhysicianItemId + '-' + slitem.get_id()] = {
                    "name":  tempPhysicianDetailsObj["name"],
                    "image": tempPhysicianDetailsObj["image"],
                    "url": tempPhysicianDetailsObj["url"],
                    "streetAddress": slitem.get_item("LocationAddress"),
                    "addressLocality": slitem.get_item("LocationLU_x003A_LocationCity").get_lookupValue()
                }
            }
         }); 
    
    }

function buildSEOSchemaBlock(){ }  //process physicianDetailsObj
```

`getPhysicianLocationDetailsFromServiceLocations` is an async function which is called inside `preparePhysicianSchemaData`

Comment: Does `preparePhysicianSchemaData` return a `Promise`?  Or is it synchronous?

Comment: its asynchronous as there is an async function that gets called inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `preparePhysicianSchemaData` is synchronous then you don't need to await it, just perform the operation after it.  Something like this:

```
getListItem(listID, itemID).then(function() {
  preparePhysicianSchemaData();
  buildPhysicianSchemaBlock();
});
```

Or if there are results you need from the Promise, something like:

```
getListItem(listID, itemID).then(function(result) {
  preparePhysicianSchemaData(result);
  buildPhysicianSchemaBlock();
});
```

---

If it's *asynchronous* then you can chain the Promises, something like:

```
getListItem(listID, itemID)
  .then(function(result) { return preparePhysicianSchemaData(result); })
  .then(function(newResult) { return buildPhysicianSchemaBlock(newResult); });
```

Basically each call to `.then()` passes the result of the previous Promise to the new asynchronous function, returning that function's Promise.

Comment: how would this setup change if  `preparePhysicianSchemaData` runs some async code inside it?

Comment: @AJSwift: I've updated the answer with an example.  Basically you can chain as many Promises together as you like using `.then()`, as long as each one returns another Promise.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute functions in strict order one after another, use async/await and Promises, have a look at this demo

```js
// Use async
(async () => {
  // Function 1
  const fn1 = (val) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Do some stuff here
      val = val + 1;
      // Resolve result.
      // Can be resolved from any level
      // of nested function!
      function nested1() {
        function nested2() {
          resolve(val);
        }
        nested2();
      }
      nested1();
    });
  };
  
  // Function 2
  const fn2 = (val) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Do some stuff here
      val = val * 2;
      // Resolve result
      resolve(val);
    });
  };
  
  // Function 3
  const fn3 = (val) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Do some stuff here
      val = val + 1000;
      // Resolve result
      resolve(val);
    });
  };
  
  // Async code
  let val = 5;
  
  val = await fn1(val); // Wait until fn1 resolves
  val = await fn2(val); // Wait until fn2 resolves
  val = await fn3(val); // Wait until fn3 resolves
  
  console.log(val);
})();
```